# get foreign key related data in django using filter

Tags: django, django-models

This is the model :

```
class Requirement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
      User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'user'
    )
    assigned_user = models.ForeignKey(
      User,related_name = "assigned",on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

I am running this query:

```
requirementsOb = Requirement.objects.filter(user = currentUser)
```

Where currentUser is logged in user. The result returns multiple requriements. I also want to get all user related data. How can i get user related data **only for assigned_use**r

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
current_user = request.user
requirements = current_user.user.all() | current_user.assigned.all()
```

Or you can try this approach:

```
requirementsOb = Requirement.objects.filter(Q(user = currentUser) | Q(assigned_user=currentUser))
```

If you want to get user data from requirements, you can try:

```
for r in requirementsOb:
    r.user
    r.assigned_user
```

If you want to get only the first requirement from the requirementsOb, then try like this:

```
requirement = requirementsOb.first() # or .last() for last object
requirement.user
requirement.assigned_user
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/).

Comment: i have modified my question. i have the current user value. I just want to get all data related to the assigned_user in query set. I believe there are simpler ways to get it .

Comment: you can loop through requirmentsOrbs (like in the answer) and access assigned_user. You can also use values `requirementOrbs.values('assigned_user__username')`. You can use prefetch related for reducing DB call: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Actually, i dont only want to access the user id..i want to get all other properties like first name, last name ,email etc of each user in the query set.

Comment: its already there. All you need to do is access them either via values or loop

Comment: NO..i am not able to access any user related data. when i try to access first_name property on user, it shows property doesnt exist.

Comment: Can you share how you have tried and what error you got in the question?